# Where do I specify nhibernate cofiguartion

Tags: c#, nhibernate, configuration

I got my `domain model` in a separate library project. And there I keep entity validators (`FluentValidation`). I read about configuration using *.xml file (and about more options). Where do I configure nhibernate. As far as I understand it should be an executable project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Fluent NHibernate, you don't need to use any configuration files at all. If you want to use plain old .hbm.xml mappings, you can choose various different locations for them. You can either put them alongside the executable as external files, or you can also add them to the embedded resources of your assembly.

You can find more detailed information and demos about this in the [Summer of NHibernate screencast series](http://summerofnhibernate.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I usually have the mapping and other configurations inside my class library and only leave the connection string to be defined on the client project (web, mvc, winforms, whatever).

I find it easier to change between development, staging and production environments.